# How to listen to Server Sent Events on client side in JMeter?

Tags: jmeter, server-sent-events

I'm looking for a way to "listen" to server sent events (sse) within JMeter for a certain amount of time or a certain content.

I haven't found a proper way yet. There is no sampler I could use. I found a javascript library [eventsource](https://github.com/EventSource/eventsource) which would help me doing this put when I try to use the content of it I receive the error:

```
message:javax.script.ScriptException: ReferenceError: "require" is not defined
```

And then something like that to use the library:

```
var source = new EventSource('/events');
source.onmessage = function(e) {
  log.info(e.data);
};
```

**What can I do to listen to sse within JMeter with the least dependencies possible (SSH command? Groovy? Java? Javascript?)?**

As an alternative I found [Gatling.io](https://gatling.io/docs/2.3/http/sse/) but I would really like to keep the dependencies as less as possible and not introduce another tool.

Comment: Why do you need it specific to jmeter?

Comment: @user7294900 because all the rest of my tests are done with JMeter. I try to avoid to introduce another tool. What else do you suggest if not possible in JMeter?

Comment: for JMeter check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27706808/how-to-include-javascript-file-in-java-program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe Groovy is a viable option, [JAX RS API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_API_for_RESTful_Web_Services) has [SseEventSource](https://github.com/jax-rs/api/blob/master/jaxrs-api/src/main/java/javax/ws/rs/sse/SseEventSource.java) class which you can use to wait for server-side events.

More information:

- [JAX-RS 2.1 SSE Client API example using Glassfish 5 on Docker](https://abhirockzz.wordpress.com/2017/07/27/jax-rs-2-1-sse-client-api-example-using-glassfish-5-on-docker/)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Comment: thank you for your reply. Is there an example how to import an external class into groovy so I could use it. I tried with `import javax.ws.rs.client.Client;

Client sseClient;`

Comment: You need to add JAX RS jars into [JMeter Classpath](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath) first