# Execute all javascript in a webpage before parsing

Tags: java, javascript, html, parsing, jsoup

I want to download the html of a web page containing some javascript. If I use a library like jsoup, I obtain the html without the elements generated by the javascript.

How can I take the html obtained after the javascript execution?

edit: How can I use the script in the answer in Java program?

Comment: If you want to *execute* (not just read) the JavaScript on a web site, you need to run [a headless Web browser](https://gist.github.com/evandrix/3694955) instead of using an HTML parser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) with the following script:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open('http://stackoverflow.com',function(status){
  if(status !== 'success'){
    console.log('Open failed');
  }else{
   console.log(page.evaluate(function(){
                               return document.documentElement.outerHTML;
                             }));
  }
  phantom.exit();
});
```

If you want execute this script from Java read the following :

[Running Phantomjs from javascript, JSP or Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16889950/running-phantomjs-from-javascript-jsp-or-java)

Comment: thanks for the answer. But I have always a problem: If I use this script with the code shown in the link, my program go in loop and I have no answer. What can i do to resolve this problem?? thanks

Comment: The best is to ask a new question with full details.